# Asp.Net MVC placeholder to hide in edit mode

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I have a asp.net mvc application with page where i am showing project title in a textbox with place holder. How can I hide this when project controls are in edit mode?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @placeholder = "Project Title", @Value = @Model.Title == null ? "New Project Title" : Model.Title })
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `Id` attribute, and use change function:

```
$('#Element').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'Project Title') { // so, it is edit mode.
    $('#Element').attr("placeholder","");
    // or
    $('#Element').removeAttr("placeholder");
  }
  else
  {
    // it is create mode.
  }
});
```

Comment: How can I detect if asp.net mvc page is in edit mode?

Comment: I meant you have edit page separately. If you write your more details about mode, I can help you. Do you have edit page or not

Comment: As I am using @Html.TextBoxFor I will be taking same page for display and edit. I am trying to get point where i can differentiate both page modes.

Comment: Your save mode is here too? If not, you can use jquery line inside change function. definde @onchange = "onchangeFunction();" and add code inside function onchangeFunction(){  }

Comment: if @Model.Title == null, is it create mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can write jquery code on edit page load to solve this issue.
Try this

> $('#ElementID').attr("placeholder","");